# What are all of the primary extant Sunni Hadith books?

Tags: hadith, sunnah, sunni, uloom-al-hadith

Based on what I have usedand some googling, I currently have:

1. Sahifah Hammam
2. Musnad Abu Hanifa
3. Musannaf Ibn Jurayj
4. Al jami’ - Ma’mar Ibn Rashidmus
5. Muwatta Maalik
6. Al Athar - al Shaybani
7. Muwatta Ibn Wahbb
8. Musnad al Tayalisi
9. Musnad al Shafi’i
10. Sunan al Ma’thur - al Shafi’i
11. Musannaf Abd al Razzaq
12. Sunan Sa’id Ibn Mansur
13. Musnad Ishaq Ibn Rahwayh
14. Musnad Ahmad Ibn Hanbal
15. Sunan al Darimi
16. Sahih al Bukhari
17. Sahih Muslim
18. Sunan Abu Dawud
19. Sunan Ibn Majah
20. Jami al Tirmidhi
21. Sunan al Nasa’i
22. Sunan al Kubra - al Nasa’i
23. Sahih Ibn Khuzaymah
24. Musnad al Siraj
25. Musnad Humaydi
26. Musannaf Ibn Abi Shaybah
27. Musnad al Bazzar
28. Musnad Abu Ya’la
29. Tahdhib al Athar
30. Musnad Abu Awanah
31. Sahih Ibn Hibban
32. al Mu’jam al Kabir - al Tabarani
33. al Mu’jam al Saghie - al Tabarani
34. al Mu’jam al Aswat - al Tabarani
35. Sunan al Daraqutni
36. al Mustadrak - al Haakim
37. Sunan al Kubra - al Bayhaqi

please tell me what I missed so I can build a comprehensive list of primary sunni Hadith collections.

Also what I mean by primary:
A Hadith collection that the Author collected based on what was narrated to him.

So it can’t be a collection like 40 Hadiths of al Nawawi which is just a book of Hadiths extracted from primary collections

Comment: Please be aware that list questions are hardly on-topic on stackexchange. Further I suppose that 29. Tahdhib al Athar refers to the book of imam at-Tabari. And finally and this is unclear to me should the collections you want to have still be existing in any kind of form? Or should they just being quoted somewhere?

Comment: extant plz. I cannot really use the books we know longer have, although that raises another question about whether the lost hadith books could have contained crucial Hadiths that we no longer have access to

Comment: A further unclarity is whether the book is attributed to the author or is compiled by him for example imam abu Hanifa didn't compile any hadith book however his students gathered 15 or 17 musnads from the hadith he was memorizing and quoting. As stated by al-Kattani in his ar-Rissalah al-Mustatrifah. There are also books referring to a hadith in other books, but only quoting a different chain and addiotional information.

Comment: Honestly even if you reduced the topic to a category of hadith or a century it would be a huge task. You need to find a good focus!

Comment: i see, shall i delete the question ? I got another question on if theres a primary hadith book compiled after Bayhaqi, pls answer

Answer (score 0):

These are enough collections which in my knowledge nearly contain all hadith we have from mauzu(fabricated) to mutawatir (mass transmitted)
If someone has read all of them (under a teacher or teachers) and understand it (which will take years) with knowledge of rijal he will be considered a great muhaddis in urf (custom)
But there are many collection of hadith missing from it. Those missing collection can at Max provide more isnad of hadith or maybe (very less likely) some more hadith (that will be most likely zaif) "LIKELY"
Alhamdulillah the great scholar Imam Ziya-ur-Rahman Azmi (1943 CE – 30 July 2020 CE).who just passed away has done a great work regarding collection of hadith and naming of hadith books which seemingly no one has done till date in which he mentions books he used u can check the list which imam ziya ur rahman provided in
his book Al-Jamiul Kamil Fee Al-Hadith As-Sahih Al-Shamil
List of hadith books are also in
Sunni collections of hadith
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hadith_books
There can be mistakes in Wikipedia you can directly check book (it's in arabic)
https://archive.org/details/jami-kamil-vol-1-12